# SQL: Restrict records in join based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**Updated issue**:

I Have two tables in following form:
table1:
title | weekend_date |

table2:
title | dateid | numerical_column

Using an inner join on 'title' column I want to pull a sum of values in numerical column with rows dated 7 days before weekend_dt of table 1. I am able to join query but stuck in calculating sum.

Here's my query:

```
select * 
  from table1 
 inner join table2 
    on table1.title=table2.title 
 where table2.date BETWEEN table1.wknd_dt - '7' and table1.wknd_dt
```

It yields following output:

```
title | dateid| numerical_column
title1| dateid| value1
title1| dateid| value2
title1| dateid| value3
title2| dateid|     value4
title2| dateid|     value5
```

So currently, due to inner join, I am getting a lot of multiple matches on titles and thus multiple records are getting pulled

What I want instead is :

```
title | dateid|numerical_column
title1| dateid|SUM(value1+value2+value3)
title2| dateid| SUM(value4+value5)
```

How Do I do that?

Comment: Where is `dateid` coming from?

Comment: my bad.  table2: title | date | numerical_column is actually                             table2: title | **dateid** | numerical_column

Comment: I have updated the issue

Comment: Is dateid a date value, integer referencing some date table, varchar...? It is usually best to provide the actual table CREATE statements.

Comment: dateid is a date value but in integer form. eg, 20170909. The weekend_date is also in same form.

Answer (score 2):

use SUM() and GROUP BY

```
SELECT t1.title,
       t1.dateid,
       SUM(t2.numerical_column) 
  FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.title = t2.title 
 WHERE t2.date BETWEEN t1.wknd_dt - 7 AND t1.wknd_dt
 GROUP BY t1.title,
          t1.dateid
```